# Char using scanner then to ascii and uppercase. Plus if and exit issues

Tags: java, if-statement, ascii, java.util.scanner, exit

I know this is a dumb question but this is my first time taking anything relating to computer science. My assignment is to make the user input their first initial of their first name, and the first initial of their last name. I'm supposed to display it in capital letters. Then I'm supposed to make the program convert the letters to ASCII. After that, I need to make it so when you put in a number like 9. It needs to show invalid input and the program should exit. I don't know how to use the if else statement or make it exit. Please help and thank you.

An example of the first part of the input and output would be:

Input:

```
Enter the first initial of your first name: j
Enter the first initial of your last name: p
```

Output:

```
Initials: J P
Encrypted Name: 74 80
```

An example of the second part of the input and output would be:

```
Input: Enter the first initial of your first name: j
Enter the first initial of your last name: 9

Initials: J Invalid Input
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TopSecretEH {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the first intial of your first name: ");

        //String firstInitial = kbReader.next().toUpperCase();// I tried it this way the first time, but apparently I'm not even supposed to go through string.
        char firstInitial = kbReader.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.print("Enter the first initial of your last name: ");

        //String lastInitial = kbReader.next().toUpperCase();
        char lastInitial = kbReader.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Initials: " + firstInitial + " " + lastInitial);

        int firstInitial2 = (int) firstInitial;
        int lastInitial2 = (int) lastInitial;
        System.out.println("Encrypted Name: " + firstInitial2 + " " + lastInitial2);

        // if (firstInitial.equals("1"))//why is my if statement not working?
        // System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        // System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `firstInitial` is defined as a `char` - You are treating it like a `String` object.  Search how to compare `char` values

Comment: You have the right idea and the battle is almost won: `char firstInitial = kbReader.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);`. To validate the input: `if ((int)firstInitial < 65 || (int)firstInitial > 90) { System.out.println(Character.toString(firstInitial) + " Is An Invalid Entry!"); System.exit(0); }`. Find and print out a good old ASCII Chart from the web.

Comment: `char x = 'a';
     if (x < 'b') System.out.println("yes");`

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thank you so much! I was a little scared since this is my first time posting, but you have been very helpful and nice! Thank you.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you for answering, I'm going to search up char and strings and how to treat them differently. Thank you so much!